# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.mouse'; 'pynput' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal

I have seen resolutions for this issue for PyCharm and VSCode, but I am getting this error on Terminal on my Mac.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from pynput.mouse import Controller

def mouse_control():
    mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()
    mouse.position = (100, 200)

mouse_control()
```

The output/error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pynput.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller
  File "/Users/uerter/Documents/Python/Key-Logger/pynput.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.mouse'; 'pynput' is not a package
```

Python3 used to show a similar path to python:

```
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which python
/usr/bin/python
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

but now shows this and I'm not sure what changed:

```
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

and when I check pip and pynput I get this:

```
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which pynput
pynput not found
MacPro-16-2398 ~ %
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled pip3 and pynput. Also, this works in IDLE.

```
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % python3
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I've now pulled out the 4 hairs that I had and am losing my mind. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so there are still issues (perceived of course) with the PATH that is being displayed and why I am getting back this output:

```
MacPro-16-2398 ~ % which pynput
pynput not found
MacPro-16-2398 ~ %
```

when I type the "which" command, BUT, I think I figured out why I was getting the this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pynput.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller
  File "/Users/uerter/Documents/Python/Key-Logger/pynput.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.mouse'; 'pynput' is not a package
```

I believe it was due to the filename that I gave it. I assume it is in conflict with the module itself. Once I changed it to "pynput_logger.py" (and fixed the "mouse" variable) everything started working as expected. My apologies for the fire drill!